# Matrix manipulation issues - colMeans

Tags: r, matrix

I was doing some pretty simple stuff in R and I found this issue which I can't figure out. 
I was standardizing some variables that were held in a matrix and found that the result was not giving what I thought it should. I have written a small example:

```
t = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3) ## data
t
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Now my question is, why do the following code not give the same answer?

```
t[1,] - colMeans(t)
[1] -1 -1 -1

(t - colMeans(t))[1,]
[1] -1  2  5
```

The correct answer is the former, however I was wondering if someone could explain to me why the latter is occuring?

If anyone could suggest a way to do the former without any loops (which is why I was trying the latter) that would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

**EDIT**

(Changing the t matrix to x to remove confusion)

```
t(t(x) - colMeans(x))
```

gives the answer I want. Is this the only way? The amount of transformations seems excessive.

Comment: Did you look at `colMeans(t)`, `t[1,]`, and `(t - colMeans(t))` individually?  Lots of info there.

Comment: Yes. The means are less the columns, rather than the rows (which is what I want). I tried (t - t(colMeans(t))) but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all these transpositions to make the correct operations on vector/matrices, or you can construct a matrix from the means of the columns:

```
> means.mat = matrix(colMeans(x),nrow=nrow(x),ncol=ncol(x),byrow=T)
> means.mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    2    5    8
> x-means.mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1   -1   -1
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    1
```